# Shrinking images using recursion incorrect positioning

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am writing code that takes an image and creates subimages within the original image. I am doing this recursively with a rectangle class that keeps track of starting and stopping positions of the subimage. After the 3rd recursive call is where i run into trouble. The new subimages are being placed in the incorrect spots. They should be shrinking as they approach the top right corner of the image. I have run through the debugger and watched the start and stop positions change with each call and they reflect movement toward the top right corner. The only place I think the error could be is where I create a new rectangle called `rRight` to be put into the recursive call.

[image]

```
int main()
{
    CImage original("test256.gif");

    Rectangle rPrev(0, 0, original.getRows(), original.getCols());
    Rectangle r(0, 0, (original.getRows() / 2), (original.getCols() / 2));
    CImage final = fractal(original, r, rPrev);

    final.output("output.gif");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

CImage fractal(CImage &origin, Rectangle &r, Rectangle &rPrev)
{
    if (r.getX2() - r.getX1() > 0 && r.getY2() - r.getY1() > 0)
    {
        drawTopLeft(origin, r, rPrev);

        Rectangle rRight(0, r.getY2(), (r.getX2() / 2), (r.getY2() + ((r.getY2() - r.getY1()) / 2)));
        fractal(origin, rRight, r);
    }
    return origin;
}

void drawTopLeft(CImage &origin, Rectangle &r, Rectangle &rPrev)
{
    for (int row = rPrev.getX1(); row < rPrev.getX2(); row += 2)
    {
        for (int col = rPrev.getY1(); col < rPrev.getY2(); col += 2)
        {
            pixel p1 = origin.getPixel(row, col);
            pixel p2 = origin.getPixel(row + 1, col);
            pixel p3 = origin.getPixel(row, col + 1);
            pixel p4 = origin.getPixel(row + 1, col + 1);

            int avgRed = (p1.red + p2.red + p3.red + p4.red) / 4;
            int avgGreen = (p1.green + p2.green + p3.green + p4.green) / 4;
            int avgBlue = (p1.blue + p2.blue + p3.blue + p4.blue) / 4;

            origin.setPixel((row / 2) + r.getX1(), (col / 2) + r.getY1(), avgRed, avgGreen, avgBlue);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you create `rRight` you're using an X1 of 0.  Should this be something else?

Comment: It seems not to be Visual C++, but C++/CLI! Did I guess right?